# simple jquery calculator with data from a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make a calculator on jquery that does the basic operations (+, -, *, /). The operands are taken from a form input and the operation from a form select. The result is printed on a form label. 
At this point it sums the 2 values which any of the options selected.
Heres my code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var op = $( "#operacion" ).val();

if ( op == "suma") {
    $('#calcular').click(function(){
        suma = parseFloat($('#operador1').val()) + parseFloat($('#operador2').val());
        $("#res").text(suma);
    }); 
}
else if ( op == "resta") {
    $('#calcular').click(function(){
        resta = parseFloat($('#operador1').val()) - parseFloat($('#operador2').val());
        $("#res").text(resta);
    }); 
}
else if ( op == "multiplicacion") {
    $('#calcular').click(function(){
        multiplicacion = parseFloat($('#operador1').val()) * parseFloat($('#operador2').val());
        $("#res").text(multiplicacion);
    }); 
}
else {
    $('#calcular').click(function(){
        division = parseFloat($('#operador1').val()) / parseFloat($('#operador2').val());
        $("#res").text(division);
    }); 
}
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to be able to substract, multiply and divide not just add the two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the "op" inside of the click function.
Something like:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){

  $('#calcular').click(function(){
    var op = $( "#operacion" ).val();
    var result;
    if ( op == "suma") {
      result = parseFloat($('#operador1').val()) + parseFloat($('#operador2').val());
    }
    else if ( op == "resta") {
      result = parseFloat($('#operador1').val()) - parseFloat($('#operador2').val());
    }
    // ....
    
    $('#res').text(result);
  }); 
});
```

Reason: you save the operator at page load, which is always the first element in the select (if not other is selected by attribute).